# Handling realtime data with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, iot

So, I am playing with these temperature sensors and I have a REST API structure to retrieve current temperature. In the front end, I have my angularJs code and I want to be able to see my data real time.

So, say this is my service call

```
getTemperature: function(){
   return $http({
     method:'GET',
     url:'https://someurltoget/device10/temperature',
     header:{
            'Accept':'application-json'},
     }).then(
      function(response){
         return response;
    },function(error){
         return error;})}
```

in my controller, I call this service, and update my view. But, temperature values update themselves in every 60 seconds, and I want this call to update my view accordingly.

However, I am not sure which way would be the best practice to get real-time data simultaneously.

I can only think of using $interval and update the view every 60 sec. but I feel like this is not the best way to resolve this problem.

So, any idea how can this be accomplished in its best way in AngularJS?

Comment: I'd say use $timeout

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTML5 technology named Web Sockets. Which Mozilla describes as follows:

> **WebSockets** is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

Web Sockets opens a constant flow of data based on events on the server, which means that you no longer need to send a request, the server can listen to an event which can be the creation of a new entry and automatically JavaScript refreshes the data in the browser side.

See this reference for further clarification: [Writing an AngularJS App with Socket.IO](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/)

Support reading:
[Mozilla MDN: WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)